# Storing a list of functions

Tags: apache-flex, google-maps

**The code**

```
for ( var i:int = 0; i < markers.length; i++ )
{
    markers[i].addEventListener( MapMouseEvent.CLICK, function( e:Event ):void
    {
        markers[i].openInfoWindow( infoWindows[i] );
    });
    map.addOverlay( markers[i] );
}
```

I have a list of markers in `markers` array, and a list of associated InfoWindowOptions in the `infoWindow` array.

**The Issue**

By the time the marker is clicked and the anonymous function called, the for loop has already finished and `i` is now equal to `markers.length`. So I get an out of bounds error on `markers[i]` and `infoWindows[i]`.

I would like to create a list of associated functions as well and store it in an array. So I can do something like this instead:

```
for ( var i:int = 0; i < markers.length; i++ )
{
    markers[i].addEventListener( MapMouseEvent.CLICK, markerListeners[i] );
}
```

So what I need to know is either,

- How can I can store a list of function references in an array?
- Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

I'm going to attempt a better way of doing this. First of all, it's good to avoid every putting an anonymous function in an addEventListener because you won't be able to remove that listeners and it won't be garbage collected -- so your application will have memory leaks.

With that said, a `Dictionary` would be perfect for this purpose.

Instead of maintaing two separate arrays and trying to link them together the key:value syntax of a Dictionary will greatly simplify your workflow.

First you should setup your Dictionary:

```
var markersDictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);

//you didn't show how you create your arrays so I'm showing
//you how to create a dictionary manually.
//this can also be done in a loop
markersDictionary[marker] = new InfoWindow(); // This should be whatever is in your infoWindows array
markersDictionary[marker] = new InfoWindow();
markersDictionary[marker] = new InfoWindow();
```

Now to add listeners:

```
for(var key:Object in markersDictionary)
{
  var marker:Marker = markersDictionary[key];
  marker.addEventListener(MouseMapEvent.CLICK, markerClickhandler, false, 0, true);
  //...false, 0, true is for weak event listeners, you should get in
  // the habit of always doing this unless you have a reason to otherwise.
{
```

and of course you need to define `markerClickhandler`:

```
function markerClickhandler(event:MouseMapEvent):void
{
  var marker:Marker = event.target as Marker;

  marker.openInfoWindow(InfowWindow(markersDictionary[marker]);
}
```

Comment: +1 for detailed explanation. Memory leak might be defeated by using weak reference argument in addEventListener, but anonymous handlers approach was bad anyway. I also would not create all InfoWindows at once, if it can be done after marker clicked (this is note for question author).

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I don't know enough details about the application to give proper advice. I showed them instantiated that way just so the author could see how a dictionary works.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a better way of doing this?

Good question. Marker should be the target of MapMouseEvent, so you can use regular function and distinguish markers by target.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the bounds error, you need to get the *value* for `i` rather than the reference, which is being kept in your anonymous handler function.  I'm sure there is a more elegant way to accomplish that than the following, but this is what I got to do the trick:

```
    for ( var i:int = 0; i < markers.length; i++ )
    {
        markers[i].addEventListener( MapMouseEvent.CLICK, createMapMouseEventHandler(i));
        map.addOverlay( markers[i] );
    }
    ...
}

private function createMapMouseEventHandler(index:int):Function
{
    return function( e:Event ):void
        {
            markers[index].openInfoWindow( infoWindows[index] );
        }
}
```

Note: If `markers` and/or `infoWindows` is outside the scope of the createMapMouseEventHandler you'll need to pass them as parameters.